# Why are there chinese icons showing on this website

Tags: html, css, wordpress, font-awesome

I am trying to figure out why there are Chinese icons showing on this wordpress website, where it should be calendar icons.

http://www.cica-criminalinjuries.com/online-claim-form/

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I cant figure out how to set them as the icons they should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your  tag :

**before:**

```
<i class="icon-calendar"></i>
```

**modify :**

```
<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
```

you can find list here : [LINK](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/)